# Project Android not compiling with Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

> k-9-master\k9mail\src\main\res\values\themes.xml:126: error: Error
>   retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given
>   name '@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog'.

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: And why does the sun come up, or are the stars just pinholes in the curtain of night? Who knows. Please provide a context - when are you getting the error, what did you do, did it work before, this kind of stuff :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible causes of an error. However, if you simply do not see any reason this should be occurring, try a project clean, or simply create a new project and pull over all the files you intended to add to this project.

This is fairly likely to solve your issue as XML files often seem to cause me random problems - i.e. one day it is working, and the next time I open my project (e.g. if put it in different folder and bring it back to same location) it might not be working. I think Eclipse and Android Studio like to edit XML files by themselves sometimes without you knowing about it for some reason unbeknown to me.